# sendSynchronousRequest crashes on slow net connection?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am using the `sendSynchronousRequest` method on `NSURLConnection` to load an image from a server. It works fine when the network connection is fast, but crashes my app when the connection is slow. What am I doing wrong?

```
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];            
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\";filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n",uploadImageName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];            
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(Obj1.thumbImage, 0.5)]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];

NSData *returndata=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:postRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *string=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:returndata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *error; 
NSString *path;
NSData *imageData;

if (error != nil && [string isEqualToString:@"success"]) {
    //doing other work
}
```

I use a background thread to run all of this code. When I upload more images while the net connection is slow the app crashes.

Comment: what error do u get when it crashes? and at which line it crashes?

Comment: i could not get it because it happening in rare situation.what might be reason for it?

Comment: can you test it while putting breakpoints.. the code seems ok as per it is shown here. maybe you could add more code here would solve the problem.

Comment: did you get any crash log ?

Comment: i am running above code in performSelectorInBackGround method

Comment: In your NSURLConnection you set `error:nil`, that means `don't bother me with errors, everything will be ok`. Then you define a `NSError *error;` and you're checking it with `error != nil`?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, I don't see anything obvious in the code snippet, itself, that would cause a crash. At the end of this answer, I provide a code sample of what I've done, so maybe you can cross reference this against yours.

A couple of thoughts:

1. You say this works on fast connection, but not slow connection. This is symptomatic of running synchronous queries from main thread. If you accidentally did this synchronous call from the main queue, on a slow connection the watchdog process might kill your app. It does so whenever the main thread is not responsive.

   So use asynchronous call (as you pursued in your other question) or make sure this is happening in the background queue.

   By the way, you say you submit this to the background thread using `performSelectorInBackground`. Most people nowadays would use GCD or `NSOperationQueue`. See the [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091).
2. Generally if there were exceptions, I'd ask you to check some of your variables:

   - You don't show us the `alloc`/`init` of the `postData`. If that's `nil` or was a `NSData` instead of a `NSMutableData`, you could get an exception.
   - You should make sure that `Obj1.thumbImage` is not `nil`. That might cause an exception, too.

   Frankly, if this is working on fast connection and not slow one, the problem is less likely to be in the basic setting of these variables, but rather whether you're updating them asynchronously elsewhere (and not synchronizing your updates per the [Synchronization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1) section of the *Threading Programming Guide* or queues via [Eliminating Lock-Based Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW3) in the *Concurrency Programming Guide*). When writing thread-safe code, you need to be careful about synchronizing changes and is some cases the speed of the connection can affect the behavior.
3. If these two points don't solve your problem, then we really need to dig into your exception. Needless to say, whenever you post any question about an exception, you have to:

   - tell us what the exception is
   - identify the line that is causing the exception; you can do this by

     - Look at the stack trace to narrow down the source of the problem;
     - Try [adding an exception breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html); Sometimes this will identify the precise line that caused the exception.
     - If that doesn't work, try single stepping through the code in the debugger.
     - The least graceful way of diagnosing the problem is adding a bunch of `NSLog` statements, so you can figure out how far the code got before crashing and that the various variables are the values you expected.
4. If you forgive the observation, while I appreciate your trying to spare us from too much code (sometimes people post tons of irrelevant code; so thanks for sparing us that), you are generally not sharing not enough code. Nine times out of ten, bugs/exceptions that people are suffering are a result of some simple variable has not been set to what you think it has (e.g. not initialized, etc.). So you either need to include slightly more complete code samples, or your code snippets should include `NSLog`, `if`, or `assert` statements that demonstrate that the values are valid.

   For example, you might want to throw in a

   ```
   if ([NSThread isMainThread])
   {
       NSLog(@"%s: should not be on main thread!!!", __FUNCTION__);
   }
   ```

   This could assure yourself this is running on a background thread. You might also want to log `Obj1.thumbImage` and `postBody` while you're at it.

   I've seen a few of your questions where you (a) post some simple code, (b) tell us that it's crashing somewhere in this snippet (but not precisely where) and (c) assure us that the values passed to the very simple code snippet are all valid (even though the snippet doesn't illustrate that). The simple reality that generally not all three of these conditions can be true at the same time. When people post crashes, the problem is as often in the variables passed to the offending code as the code itself.

A few unrelated points:

1. As an aside, In your `sendSynchronousRequest`, you're specifying `nil` for the `error`. If an API affords you the opportunity to diagnose the success or failure of the error, you should avail yourself of that.
2. Using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` really is a worst-case scenario with significant loss of data. If humanly possible, go back to the source of the `UIImage` (how was it created? a `NSData`?). If you can't do that, maybe consider `UIImagePNGRepresentation` because that still enjoys compression, but less data loss. Sometimes you have to do `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`, but consider it a tool of last resort.
3. If your server only returns "success" text string, then I guess that's all you can do. If possible, it's better if you can program your server to return a JSON response for which you can easily consume/parse different return codes for different types of errors/responses.

Anyway, here is a working upload routine:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(upload) withObject:nil];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my.url.com/upload.php"];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myimage" ofType:@"jpg"]; // note, I'm going back to bundle, not grabbing `UIImage` from imageview

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        [self uploadFileAtPath:path
                      forField:@"file"
                           URL:url
                    parameters:nil];
    });
}

- (NSString *)generateBoundaryString
{
    // generate boundary string
    //
    // adapted from http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleURLConnections
    //
    // Note in iOS 6 and later, you can just:
    //
    //    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Boundary-%@", [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];

    CFUUIDRef  uuid;
    NSString  *uuidStr;

    uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    assert(uuid != NULL);

    uuidStr = CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid));
    assert(uuidStr != NULL);

    CFRelease(uuid);

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Boundary-%@", uuidStr];
}

- (NSString *)mimeTypeForPath:(NSString *)path
{
    // Get a mime type for an extension using MobileCoreServices.framework.
    //
    // You could hard code this instead, but I like using MobileCoreServices as
    // it increases my code reuse possibilities in the future.

    CFStringRef extension = (__bridge CFStringRef)[path pathExtension];
    CFStringRef UTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, extension, NULL);
    assert(UTI != NULL);

    NSString *mimetype = CFBridgingRelease(UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(UTI, kUTTagClassMIMEType));
    assert(mimetype != NULL);

    CFRelease(UTI);

    return mimetype;
}

- (void)uploadFileAtPath:(NSString *)imagePath
                forField:(NSString *)fieldName
                     URL:(NSURL*)url
              parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
{
    NSString *filename = [imagePath lastPathComponent];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

    NSMutableData *httpBody = [NSMutableData data];
    NSString *boundary = [self generateBoundaryString];
    NSString *mimetype = [self mimeTypeForPath:imagePath];

    // configure the request

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:30];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // set content type

    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    // add params (all params are strings)

    [parameters enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *parameterKey, NSString *parameterValue, BOOL *stop) {
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", parameterKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", parameterValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }];

    // add image data

    if (imageData) {
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", fieldName, filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n", mimetype] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [httpBody appendData:imageData];
        [httpBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust

    [request setHTTPBody:httpBody];

    NSError *error;
    NSData *returndata = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error=%@", error);
        return;
    }

    // I generally return JSON response, so this is where I parse it;
    // obviously, your validation process will differ.

    NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returndata options:0 error:&error];

    if (error)
        NSLog(@"error=%@", error);
    if (results)
        NSLog(@"result=%@", results);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

to track this down...

add an exception breakpoint. That will stop the debugger right on the line the exception happens on.

background threads do not have their own exception handlers, so they will generate a signal and crash your process. so you can add your own especially for something like this, where the system call is generating the exception and you don't have a good way to prevent it.

```
@try{

    NSData *returndata=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:postRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *string=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:returndata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}

@catch(NSException *e)
{
    NSLog(@"caught exception: %@",e);
    //you could also iterate over: - (NSArray *)callStackSymbols NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);
}
```